# How to express "each" for this sentence?

Tags: expressions

Research concluded there were five groups of species, which have specific patterns for nest selection **for each.**

Does "for each" in that sentence explain that each of five groups has specific pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I think so, though it is a bit ambiguous.

But a better way to write this based on what you said (each of five groups has a specific pattern) might be:

> Research concluded there were five groups of species, **each of** which has specific patterns for nest selection.